# Vue upgradation from vue 2 to vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am upgrading vue 2 project to vue 3 project. After changed the code to vue 3, it shows as in below code segment.

```
    export default defineComponent ({
            name : 'SubmitExpenseClaim',
            components: {
                ClientsList,
                ExpenseClaimLineCard,
                Modal,
                DataTable,
                TimeCountdown
            },
            mixins: [validationMixin],
            validations: {
                expenseClaim: {
                    clientId: {
                        required,
                        minValue: minValue(1)
                    },
                    employmentId: {
                        required,
                        minValue: minValue(1)
                    },
                    accountID: {
                        required,
                        minValue: minValue(1)
                    }
                }
            },
            props : {
                item : {
                    isManual : Boolean,
                    default: false
                },
            },
    
            todayDate: new Date() as any,
            todayDateUTC: new Date(Date.UTC(this.todayDate.getFullYear(), this.todayDate.getMonth(), this.todayDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0)) as any,
            expenseClaimCreatedDate : new Date(),
            initialExpenseClaim: {
                id: 0,
                timeZone: 0,
                createdByUserId: 0,
                createdDate: new Date(),
                updatedBy: "",
                lastUpdatedDate: new Date(),
                concurrencyKey: "",
                expenseClaimWizardStep: ExpenseClaimWizardStep.Summary,
                dirtyValidationRefNos: [],
                expenseClaimValidations: {
                    showTransactionCategoryErrorMessage: false,
                    showReasonErrorMessage: false,
                    showTransactionSubcategoryErrorMessage: false
                },
                isManual: false,
                selectedExpenseClaimLineId: 0
            } as ExpenseClaimModel ,
            expenseClaim: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialExpenseClaim)) as ExpenseClaimModel ,
            expenseClaimLines: [] as any[],
            initialExpenseClaimLinesCount: 1 as number ,
            isAdmin: false as boolean,
            isStandardUser: false as boolean,
            
    
            // validation errors
            readonly percentagePayableInvalidErrorMsg: "Percentage payable value is invalid." as string,
            readonly percentagePayableEmptyErrorMsg: "Percentage payable value cannot be empty." as string ,
            readonly gstInclusiveRequestedAmountInvalidErrorMsg:"Total amount (GST Inclusive) is invalid." as  string ,
            readonly gstInclusiveRequestedAmountEmptyErrorMsg: "Total amount (GST Inclusive) cannot be empty." as string ,
            readonly gstRequestedAmountInvalidErrorMsg:"Total gst amount is invalid." as string ,
            readonly gstRequestedAmountEmptyErrorMsg: "Total gst amount cannot be empty." as string ,
            readonly gstRequestedAmountLessThanCheckErrorMsg:"Total gst amount cannot be larger than total amount (GST Inclusive)." as  string ,

)}
```

In this vue file, there are an error messages called **"readonly' modifier cannot be used here.ts(1042)"** near the readonly keyword. So how can I solve this error? In here, I only posted in script part. Not the HTML part.

Comment: You can't use readonly there, that's it. It can be used in classes but not object literals. The syntax is invalid. It's unclear if this code is in data() or somewhere else.

Comment: @EstusFlask This code is in <script lang="ts"><script/> tags. However, are there any way to use readonly syntax for this one?

Comment: What's the point of having todayDate, etc properties if they aren't data? A possible solution may depend on your case, which is unclear. Usually you'd just use a const for constant string, because that's what variables are for. It's unnecessary for everything to be declared on a component.

Comment: @EstusFlask So you mentioned, all these properties like todayDate , etc should be declared in data(). Isn't it?

Comment: Then the question should reflect this. Otherwise it's unclear what your component actually looks like. You mentioned that you migrate from 2 to 3 but it wouldn't ever work this way in any Vue version. If it's data() then this is XY problem. It's for mutable data. For read-only data use computeds. Or just define them as consts as suggested above

Comment: Not only do you need to remove `readonly` from each component member using it, but also note you can't declare custom component members and expect them to work, as the component doesn't know how to interpret them. Use the provided Options API or declare them as constants in `setup` function. If you want `this.todayDate` to be usable in component's `methods` or `computed`, declare it inside `data` function, ***not on the root level of component***.

Comment: Also note Typescript infers the types of primitives, so recasting them (as in `true as boolean`, `0 as number`, `'whatever' as string`) is utterly useless. All those types are already inferred from the values, because they're primitives.

Comment: This is [probably closer](https://jsfiddle.net/b2vqo7gj/) to what you want. At least it's valid.